# Angular 2 provide() with string in ES5?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a String as a token for provide instead of a class:

```
app.RandomComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: "randomComponent",
        template: "Component!",
        providers: [
            ng.core.provide("Stuff", {useValue: "Hello"})
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: ["Stuff", function(stuff) {

        }]
    });
```

However, it throws the error: `EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'class5'(Stuff). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'class5' is decorated with Injectable.`

According to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Provider-class.html it should work at least in TS :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Inject documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/InjectMetadata-class.html).

> When @Inject() is not present, Injector will use the type annotation of the parameter.

In your case you're injecting a simple string but angular2 can't use **string** as type for your **Stuff**. So in these cases you have to use `ng.core.Inject` as follows

```js
.Class({

    // Note the ng.core.Inject
    constructor: [ng.core.Inject("Stuff"), function(stuff) {
      console.log(stuff);
    }]
});
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NgtHAK3eL7Q2tsZ9kj6N?p=preview) with your code working.